# dynamic update target id in Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

i have this code in a grid and I want to have UpdateTargetId of the action link,  div id to be changed for each row

```
<%: Ajax.ActionLink("Select", "GetCodes", "BvIndex", new { id = o.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId ="Result"})%>
 <div id ="Result"></div>
```

I tried this but i didn't get it

```
    <%: Ajax.ActionLink("Select", "GetCodes", "BvIndex", new { id = o.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId ="Result"+o.Id})%>
<div id ="Result"+"<%=o.Id%>"></div>
```

I want to have UpdateTarget id to be changed for each row in the grid, like appending id to it, and then assigning the same id to div in which i have to show the result.

Comment: netdev, i think you're gonna have to put a bit more effort into your question if you really want quality answers. you know the saying, 'sausage in sausage out'!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetDev,

I think I know what you are getting at.  You want to loop through some items and create divs and links like so:

```
<link1 targetID="Result1"/>
<div id="Result1">Some Stuff</div>
<link1 targetID="Result2"/>
<div id="Result2">Some Stuff</div>
<link1 targetID="Result3"/>
<div id="Result3">Some Stuff</div>
```

What you have is a good start, but have you looked at your rendered HTML?  I think that this:  `<div id ="Result"+"<%=o.Id%>"></div>`

is not doing what you think its doing.  The rendered HTML based on that code would look like...well bad.  `<div id="Result"+"1"></div>`

Try updating your dynamic div id naming to this instead:

```
<div id="Result<%=o.Id%>"></div>
```

Which should then render out in HTML as `<div id="Result1"></div>`