# Get ID of selected row using Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which looks like:

```
          @foreach (var car in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @car.ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    @car.carMake
                </td>
                <td>
                    @car.carModel
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="result"></div> //update result based on ID

                </td>
                <td>
                 Check for @Ajax.ActionLink(
                               @car.carMake,
                               "getUpdate",
                               "Home",
                               new { ID = car.ID },
                               new AjaxOptions
                                {
                               UpdateTargetId = "result", //use car.ID here? not sure
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                               HttpMethod = "Get"
                                })                      
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
```

What I'm trying to do is get the ID of the car that is selected and only update that row with the data from the partial view for e.g. if there are 3 cars

```
Car ID | Car Make | Car Model | result   | Get car updates
1          VW          Polo               (Ajax actionlink)       
2          BMW         3                  (Ajax actionlink)
3          Ford        Focus              (Ajax actionlink)
```

If i click on the action link for BMW, I want that row only to be updated with the partial view operation. I've tried using JQuery using:

```
ID = $('#car_ID').val(); on a @Html.HiddenFor(model => car.ID)
```

but it keeps getting the first car's ID. Not sure how I would go about doing this.

I've seen this: [dynamic update target id in Ajax.ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640074/dynamic-update-target-id-in-ajax-actionlink) but hasn't worked.

Comment: Check the Html getting generated for ActionLink. For ID property in jquery you need to do `$(element).attr("id")`

Comment: when you click on action link and on action you receive only first id?

Comment: @rem please let me know if you found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works.  Please let me know what your think, and if there is anything else you need to complete your work.
Here is how you do it.  Here is your partial view (_PartialView.cshtml):

```
model Testy20161006.Controllers.CarModel

<div>
    Updated Row: @Html.Raw(Model.CarId), @Html.Raw(Model.CarMake), @Html.Raw(Model.theCarModel) 
</div>
```

Here is your controller/model:

```
 public class CarModel
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string CarMake { get; set; }
    public string theCarModel { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult getUpdate(int carId)
    {
        CarModel carModel = new CarModel();
        switch (carId)
        {
            case 1:
                carModel.CarId = 1;
                carModel.CarMake = "updated11111Make";
                carModel.theCarModel = "updated11111Model";
                break;
            case 2:
                carModel.CarId = 2;
                carModel.CarMake = "updated2Make";
                carModel.theCarModel = "updated22222Model";
                break;
            case 3:
                carModel.CarId = 3;
                carModel.CarMake = "updated3Make";
                carModel.theCarModel = "updated33333Model";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return PartialView("_PartialView", carModel);
    }

    public ActionResult Index700()
    {
        IList<CarModel> carModelList = Setup();
        return View(carModelList);
    }
```

Here is your view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Testy20161006.Controllers.CarModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index700</title>
    @*I had to add these references*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".getClick").click(function () {
                alert("ap");
                $(".clearMe").text("");
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        @foreach (var car in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @car.CarId
                </td>
                <td>
                    @car.CarMake
                </td>
                <td>
                    @car.theCarModel
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (@car.CarId == 1)
                    {
                        <div id="result1" class="clearMe"></div> @*//update result based on ID*@
                    }
                    else if (@car.CarId == 2)
                    {
                        <div id="result2" class="clearMe"></div> @*//update result based on ID*@
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div id="result3" class="clearMe"></div> @*//update result based on ID*@
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    Check for @Ajax.ActionLink(
                  @car.CarMake,
                               "getUpdate",
                               new { carId = car.CarId },
                               new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                    UpdateTargetId = "result" + car.CarId, //use car.ID here? not sure
                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                    HttpMethod = "GET"
                                }, new { @class = "getClick" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```